# Exc bad access after populating NSMutableArray with custom class extending CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I have a PlaceAnnotation class that I fill into an NSMutableArray.  In viewDidLoad, i initiate ihatethis

```
_ihatethis = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I use a MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler to search. And handle the mapitems like this:

```
for (MKMapItem *mapItem in [response mapItems]){

     PlaceAnnotation *place = [[PlaceAnnotation alloc] init];
     [place assignTitle:[[mapItem placemark] name];

     [_ihatethis addObject:place];
}

[_ihatethis removeObjectAtIndex:2]; /*BAD ACCESS HERE*/
[_tableView reloadData];
```

This is my PlaceAnnotation.h file

```
@interface PlaceAnnotation : CLPlacemark <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary* dict;
//@property (nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *phoneNum;
@property (readonly) BOOL selected;

-(void)assignTitle:(NSString *)newTitle;
-(void)assignSelected:(BOOL) boolVal;
```

This is my PlaceAnnotation.m file

```
#import "PlaceAnnotation.h"

@interface PlaceAnnotation ()

@property (readwrite) NSString *title;
@property (readwrite) BOOL selected;

@end

@implementation PlaceAnnotation

-(void) assignTitle:(NSString *)newTitle {
    if ( ![newTitle isEqualToString:[self title]]){
        self.title = newTitle;
    }
}

-(void) assignSelected:(BOOL)boolVal{
    self.selected = boolVal;
}

@end


@end
```

This is my first post, I have read a ton of answers that responded to exc_bad_access questions and I cannot figure this out.  So I think that somehow the placeannotations are getting forgotten and released. So when i go to delete is later it is gone. I really am confused and angry.

Comment: How's `_ihatethis` declared? And b.t.w. it should be `_iHateThis`. In Objective-C we're quite strict about style.

Comment: Are you using ARC or manual retain count?

Comment: Is the declaration `_ihatethis` being initialized before running through your loop? Second: does your loop have at least 3 objects being added?  (`[_ihatethis removeObjectAtIndex:2]` is removing the third object in your array).

Comment: You showed how `_ihatethis`is being initialized, but not how it is declared (e.g. `NSMutableArray *_ihatethis` or `NSArray *_ihatethis`). If it's declared as the latter, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Matt Declaring the array `NSArray` would trigger compiler warnings, not a mach (runtime) exception.

Comment: What about the differences between the property `title` in the interface versus the interface extension? Is copying still occurring when calling the method `-assignTitle:`? Or is the `title` creating a strong reference to `newTitle`?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Sorry, i switch it after getting frustrated.  it is a property of the view, declared " @property NSMutableArray *ihatethis. 

I am using ARC.  dreamlax, i dont know if it is some thing wrong with xcode 5.

Comment: Matt, the title is readonly, because that is how it is in CLPlacemark

Comment: @dreamlax , you're right.  I thought it could be something with xcode 5 because this worked in xcode 4. But it ended up being a CLPlacemark issue so I updated the title.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this

```
@interface PlaceAnnotation : CLPlacemark <MKAnnotation>
```

to this

```
@interface PlaceAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
```

so i guess the problem was with the dealloc of CLPlacemark. Thanks

Comment: It would appear the CLPlacemark is the problem.  I found that simply new'ing CLPlacemark will cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the end of the method with ARC.  I haven't been able to figure out why, but it sure makes it tough extend CLPlacemark and then test them.

Answer (score 1):

If the crash really is in this line `[_ihatethis removeObjectAtIndex:2];` and it's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS then there are two possibilities:

1. `_ihatethis` is pointing to a broken array (unlikely, if the loop went through).
2. An object in the array has been overreleased or has broken memory management in its `dealloc` method.

Comment: I am using ARC and the only objects i am using are PlaceAnnotation, a class i made to extend CLPlacemark.  Do you have any ideas of where I should look for this broken memory?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're trying to remove an item at an index greater than the array's count. Try to output the count just before `[_ihatethis removeObjectAtIndex:2];`, like this:

```
`
NSLog(@"count: %d", [_ihatethis count]);
[_ihatethis removeObjectAtIndex:2]; /*BAD ACCESS HERE*/
`
```

If the count is smaller than 3, then you're trying to remove an object at an index outside the array's bounds.

Comment: Out of bounds access would not result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS but an Objective-C exception with a proper error message.