# Extending CLPlacemark results in EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, extend, clplacemark

Though there is a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204417/exc-bad-access-after-populating-nsmutablearray-with-custom-class-extending-clpla) it does not provide an answer, at least not for the general problem.

My problem is: 
Since `CoreLocation` geocoding is rate limited and the (web-)service I am developing an app for provides its own fallback geocoding service, I want to use this custom geocoding service in case I reach Apple's rate limit. Furthermore, I feel it makes total sense to avoid a custom data type for results returned by this custom REST API and therefore would like to use the data returned to generate `CLPlacemark`s. However, the documentation states that `CLPlacemark` properties such as `location, locality, administrativeArea` etc. are `read-only`. 
I therefore created a subclass of `CLPlacemark` synthesizing the needed properties onto private variables I can access, i.e.:

```
// interface: (.h)
@interface CustomPlacemark : CLPlacemark
- (nonnull id)initWithLocation: (nonnull CLLocation *)location
                      locality: (nullable NSString *)locality                       
            administrativeArea: (nullable NSString *)adminArea
                       country: (nullable NSString *)country;
@end

// implementation (.m)
@implementation CustomPlacemark
@synthesize location = _location;
@synthesize locality = _locality;
@synthesize country = _country;
@synthesize administrativeArea = _administrativeArea;

- (nonnull id)initWithLocation: (nonnull CLLocation *)location
                          locality: (nullable NSString *)locality
                administrativeArea: (nullable NSString *)adminArea
                           country: (nullable NSString *)country{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _location = location;
        _locality = locality;
        _administrativeArea = adminArea;
        _country = country;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Testing this code with a unit test which parses data from a JSON file and calls my `initWithLocation: locality: administrativeArea: country:` method with the data results in a `EXC BAD ACCESS (code=1)` at the end of the test (at the closing `}` of the test method) with the placemark variable pointing to `nil` although a prior `NSLog(@"placemark: %@", customPlacemark);` outputs the correct values. Furthermore, stepping through the test line by line shows the `CustomPlacemark` working (i.e. pointing to a properly populated object) until reaching the end of the test. To me this indicates that something with the deallocation of my `CustomPlacemark` goes wrong - but what exactly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a reference to anyone landing here with a similar problem:

After some intensive Google-Fu and deep diving into Apple's sources, it seems as if extending `CLPlacemark` is not intended.

I was, however, able to implement a workaround based on the tips found [here](http://szulctomasz.com/unit-testing-in-swift-with-clplacemark/), which basically abuses the fact that `MKPlacemark` extends `CLPlacemark` and offers a method to initialise with custom data, namely `- (instancetype _Nonnull)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * _Nullable)addressDictionary`. Finding the right keys for the `addressDictionary` to map the desired properties in `CLPlacemark` might require some trial and error, especially since `ABPerson/Address`functionality has become deprecated with iOS 9. 
The keys I found for my purposes are:

```
@"City" -> CLPlacemark.city
@"State" -> CLPlacemark.administrativeArea
@"Country" -> CLPlacemark.country
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @hpd!

My swift mock class:

```
class TestPlacemark: CLPlacemark {
    static let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(35), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(-80))

    override init() {
        let mkPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: TestPlacemark.coordinate) as CLPlacemark
        super.init(placemark: mkPlacemark)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return false
    }
    override var location: CLLocation? {
        return CLLocation(latitude: TestPlacemark.coordinate.latitude, longitude: TestPlacemark.coordinate.longitude)
    }
    override var postalAddress: CNPostalAddress?  {
        return TestPostalAddress()
    }
}
```

Hope it saves someone else some time. Cheers!